# cloned button not filter cloned form javascript?

Tags: javascript

I cloned a form and a button but this button for filter  only affect a original form not affect to cloned form

```
    </script>
  <input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Clone Div" />
       <script>
         $("#btnClone").bind('click', function() {

     $('#buttontest').clone(true).appendTo('body'); 
        $('#prueban2').clone(true).appendTo('body');
          });
  </script>
```

i put this image for understanding purpose

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lubk6.png

the first form contain 1 to 12 number and filter with the button 
the number 3 4 10 and 11

the field in red is the cloned form this contain 1 to 12 numbers

the button only filter the first form

the field in black contain the cloned filter button

please help

Comment: can you provide a code snippet/jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this since it would work.

```js
$("#btnClone").on('click', function() {
  $('#buttontest').clone()[0].appendTo('body'); 
  $('#prueban2').clone()[0].appendTo('body');
});

// OR

$("#btnClone").click(function() {
  $("#buttontest").clone().appendTo('body');
  $("#prueban2").clone().appendTo('body');
})
```

```html
 <input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Clone Div" />
```